Check subscription status
I am currently using "Subscribe to report" option in Power BI for the first time. I use it to send filtered reports each month to company's employees. My subscription is turned off, but each month when I need to send the reports, I manually trigger it by using Send now button. Since hundreds of people are subscribed to it, I want to check the progress/status of each trigger of the subscription. Did someone fail to receive? What % is done? Does power bi store somewhere this data, because I can't find it. Manage all subscriptions page is literally only to manage/make changes but not monitor.
Thank you in advance!
